# Add Defined Variable After The First Line Of A Text File

Tags: linux, unix, text, awk, sed

I'm trying to insert a defined bash variable into a text document, after the first line:

```
sed -i "2i ${storm}" ${HOMEDIR}${PATH1}${YMD}/tmp_tc_tracks
```

The above command doesn't work for me...

Comment: Are you trying to insert the _literal string_ `${storm}` into your file, or the current value of the environment variable named `storm`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to do this? Or does your file just seem wrong?

Comment: I have set an environmental varaible called storm.

Comment: storm=`awk '{print $2} ${HOMEDIR}{PATH1}${YMD}/tmp_tc_tracks | head -2 |tail -1`

Comment: "The above command doesn't work" is not useful information.  Do you get an error message?  If so, what is it.  If not, what doesn't work?  What you have will not work in all sed, but it should work with gnu sed (I assume you are using gnu sed since you specify `-i`) if the string stored in `$storm` is of a certain type.  Does the string contain newlines or semi colons?  Much more detail is needed before this question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `$` like so:

```
sed -i "2i \${storm}" ${HOMEDIR}${PATH1}${YMD}/tmp_tc_tracks
```

It's likely that your shell is trying to find `${storm}` in your environment, but since it can't it's wigging out.

Without the escape, I see the following error:

```
ryan@bsp1:~/tmp$ sed -i "2i ${asdf}" test.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'
```

Comment: This is true. Just trying out my jump to conclusions mat, that's all.

Comment: escapeing the $ mean to not substitute it by shell, so no var substitution in this case. This is used for the litteral valu not content

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "2 i\\
${storm}" ${HOMEDIR}${PATH1}${YMD}/tmp_tc_tracks
```

Double quote needed for var substitution but this also mean escape the escape char (`\\`) needed after the `i` command and the new line folloing this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily using awk:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
$ var="new line"
$ awk -v v="$var" 'NR==2{print v}1' file
line 1
new line
line 2
line 3
```

If you want to overwrite the original file, you can do the standard trick, using an intermediate temporary file:

```
awk -v v="$var" 'NR==2{print v}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Can't get this to work either. Currently using storm=`awk '{print $2} ${HOMEDIR}{PATH1}${YMD}/tmp_tc_tracks | head -2 |tail -1`

Comment: My command works for me, it inserts the variable after the first line of the file. Judging by your command, it looks like you are trying to assign the value of `$storm`, not insert it into the file. Please update your question to make it clear exactly what you are trying to do. It would be useful to show the value of all of the variables. Also include the input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes should also work in addition to rkysers answer

```
sed -i '2i ${storm}' file
```

the double quotes enable shell expansion, single quotes treat the text as a literal